# Golang - Sending binary encoded data via TLS Socket

Tags: python, sockets, go, binary, packing

I'm new to Golang and this kind of more lowlevel stuff, so maybe i'm just thinking in the wrong direction.

My project is a small golang monitoring client which sends some ping-message (current date) over a encrypted TLS connection (this is just for learning purpose).
The python server and client are working flawless for now.

The (python) server & client are packing the data like this:

```
[...]
def _send_msg(self, msg):
    msg = struct.pack('>I', len(msg)) + bytes(msg, 'UTF-8')
    self.client.send(msg)

def _recv_msg(self):
    raw_msglen = self.client.recv(4)
    if not raw_msglen:
        return ""
    msglen = struct.unpack('>I', raw_msglen)[0]
    return self._recvall(msglen)
[...]
```

On the Go-Side I pack the data like this:

```
type packet struct {
   a uint32
   b []byte
}

func pack(d string) []byte {

    buf := bytes.Buffer{}
    u := len([]byte(d))
    p := packet{
        a: uint32(u),      
        b: []byte(d),
    }

    err := binary.Write(&buf, binary.BigEndian, p.a) // struct.unpack('>I' [...] in python 

    if err != nil {
       fmt.Println(err)
    }

    buf.Write(p.b) // Append bytes to buffer

    return buf.Bytes() 
}

reader := bufio.NewReader(tlsConn) // Socket reader

[..]
// Writing binary data
tlsConn.Write(pack("login test:test")) // Works so far

// Reading response (from python server)
var p uint32  // packet size
binary.Read(reader, binary.BigEndian, &p) // Read packet length (4 bytes uint32)
buf1 := make([]byte, int(p))
reader.Read(buf1)
fmt.Println(string(buf1)) // Print  response - this also works

// Send some ping
// This code part also get's passed, but the python server doesn't
// recive any message
c.Write(pack("ping 0000-00-00 00:00:00")) 
binary.Read(reader, binary.BigEndian, &p)
buf1 = make([]byte, int(p))
fmt.Println(string(buf1)) // Here i don't get an response
```

Here is the golang client-side test code which I'm using: http://pastebin.com/dr1mJZ9Y
and the corresponding terminal output: http://pastebin.com/mrctJPs5

The strange thing is, that the login message (including the server response) all get sent (and received) correctly but the second time when i try to send a ping like:

```
tlsConn.Write(pack("ping 0000-00-00 00:00:00"))
```

The message seems not to reach the server and no response message gets  send back to the client.

Is there an error with the binary encoding of the packet-data and the length prefixing?

I know the code looks a bit messy and not very go-idiomatic, sorry for that.
Thank you again in advance for your help!

Software dependencies / environment:

- Python 3.4
- Golang 1.5.3 (amd64 Linux)
- No 3rd-Party libs

Comment: Oh. I had similar problems starting out. Sorry I don't have time to look in depth, maybe if this is still unanswered after I get up tomorrow I'll do so, but sometimes the problem is as simple as needing to `\n` or something similar to indicate that the write is terminated... maybe that helps, and maybe someone who can take the time will get to it before I have a chance.

Comment: Jeah, i did some work and surprisingly you're right with the "\n", i also encode large messages with fancy unicode byte sequences to base64 now... But really, only god knows why its works how it works now.
It looks very ugly now: 

conn.Write(pack("\n")) 
conn.Write(pack("msgb64 " + string(b64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(out)))))

Comment: There is no need for newlines. In the code you pasted, you have `tlsCon.Write` and `c.Write`. We don't know what `c` is.

Comment: The variable "c" is actually "tlsConn". I overlooked that due a code-beautification for this post. Sorry my fault. Currently my script works with the newlinew workaround on go 1.5 - 1.6, i haven't tried the 1.7 alpha yet.